# Three.js выдает ошибку на отсутствие модуля, но он импортирован

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js выдает ошибку, почему? Уже два дня страдаю

Импорт модуля: `import { OBJLoader } from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";`

Вот эта строка: `var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();`

Вот эту ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OBJLoader is not a constructor at`

Comment: импортируете OBJLoader, а обращаетесь почему то через THREE.OBJLoader

Comment: Огромное спасибо, правда, уже два дня на этой ошибке...